# Which AWS product for a Spring MVC mobile app backend?

Tags: mysql, spring, amazon-web-services

A group and I created a mobile app that used Spring MVC connected to a MySQL database as the backend. It was for University, and the instructors set up apache tomcat servers for us, so I don't know anything about actually getting a server up and running, I just know how to write Java for Spring.

I think AWS is a good place to look but there are so many products that I'm overwhelmed and confused. Does anyone have suggestions on which product I should use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running your Java/Spring code there are 3 options

1. [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) - You would find this most straighforward if you are dont have much familiarity with AWS
2. [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) + [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/)
3. [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)

For MySQL there are 2 options

1. [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/)
2. [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) (Manually installing MySQL server)

Further, for you mobile app User Sign-Up, Sign-In, and Access Control you can check [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at EC2 and RDS. EC2 will give you an image that you can install tomcat on (or whatever you want). And if you need an database server RDS will give you a place to deploy and host your database.

If this is just for testing/learning you could also skip RDS and just install your database server on your EC2 instance but that isn't a good idea for a production app.

As you get ready to go to production you'll probably need other AWS services but EC2 is a great place to start and the way AWS works will become more clear as you get a first app running.